# pthread library not found when building executable?

Tags: c++, makefile, pthreads

I'm trying to build a simple test program for a ThreadManager class I created. As you can see in the output below, my ThreadManager and main code seems to compile into object files just fine, but then when creating the executable, it can't seem to find proper references to any of the functions from the pthread class. What am I missing?

```
g++    -c -o ThreadManager.o ThreadManager.cpp  
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp  
g++ -o tm_test ThreadManager.o main.o -g    -lm  

ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Create(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void* (*)(void*))':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `pthread_create'  
ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Create(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void* (*)(void*), void*)':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x4a3): undefined reference to `pthread_create'  
ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Create(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, void* (*)(void*), void*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x70b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'  
ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Cleanup(int)':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): undefined reference to `pthread_join'  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0xa5f): undefined reference to `pthread_join'  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0xbe1): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'  
ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Resurrect()':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0xe8c): undefined reference to `pthread_create'  
ThreadManager.o: In function `ThreadManager::Kill(int)':  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x125f): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'  
ThreadManager.cpp:(.text+0x1285): undefined reference to `pthread_join'  
ThreadManager.o:(.rodata+0x1a0): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'  
main.o:(.rodata+0x5c): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [tm_test] Error 1
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Link to the `pthread` library;

```
g++ -c -o ThreadManager.o ThreadManager.cpp 
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp 
g++ -o tm_test -lm -lpthread
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it... I don't get it though, why would I need the flag when I'm creating the executable but not when I'm creating the object files?

Comment: You need to link to the libraries when you are linking the _final_ executable. An object file contains no dependency info in itself, the executable does.